# Sequelize, postgres and posgis: find activities within n° kilometers

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, postgis

Please help!
I have a project using Sequelize, postgres and postgis (for gps).
The schema (simplified) is:

```
export default class Activity extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    return super.init({
      sequelize,
      tableName: 'activities',
    })
  }

  static get modelAttributes() {
    return {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
      },

      activity_name: {
        type: 'citext',
        allowNull: false,
        unique: {
          args: true,
          msg: 'Activity name already in use.',
        },

      point: {
        type: DataTypes.GEOMETRY,
        allowNull: true,
      },
    }
  }
}
```

I don't put the migration file, because this part works well: whene I save the data, it's correctly registered.

```
await Activity.bulkCreate({
  activity_name: 'whatever,
  point: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [lat, lng] },
})
```

The problem comes when I try to get activities within a certain distance:

```
const result = await User.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: Activity,
          required: true,
          where: {
            point: Sequelize.fn(
              'ST_DWithin',
              Sequelize.fn(
                'ST_SetSRID',
                Sequelize.fn('ST_MakePoint', 40.119536, 8.495837),
                4326
              ),
              parseFloat(distance) // number 10000
            ),
          },
        },
      ],
    })
```

This code throws an error: "function st_dwithin(geometry, integer) does not exist".
I struggling with this problem since a while. Any solution?
thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Unfortunatelly still not working, but with a different behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is two-fold:

1. [`ST_DWithin()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) requires two geometries and a distance limit. You only supplied a single geometry and the limit:

   > boolean **ST_DWithin**(geometry *g1*, geometry *g2*, double precision *distance_of_srid*);
2. [`ST_SetSRID()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html) adds the context of a reference system to the supplied geometry. You selected [EPSG:4326](https://epsg.io/4326), which uses *geographical degrees* as the base unit, not meters, not miles. There's a warning in `ST_DWithin` documentation:

   > The distance is specified in units defined by the spatial reference system of the geometries.

   Which means a distance limit of 180 already returns everything, filters nothing, because on a sphere you're always at most 180 degrees away: 181 degrees East is just 179 degrees West. [Change the SRID](https://xkcd.com/977/) or convert your units: assuming [WGS-84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#WGS_84)'s spherical Earth radius of `6371008.8m`, you can arrive at a single degree of `111195.08m` by dividing the circumference over `360` degrees: `6371008.8*2*pi/360`. A single meter is then `1/111195.08` of a degree which is why you might want to trade this:

   ```
   parseFloat(distance) * 5000
   ```

   for this

   ```
   parseFloat(distance) /111195.08
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `point` column as a first argument of `ST_DWithin` while you passed only one geometry to the function:

```js
where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn(
              'ST_DWithin',
              Sequelize.col('point'),
              Sequelize.fn(
                'ST_SetSRID',
                Sequelize.fn('ST_MakePoint', 40.119536, 8.495837),
                4326
              ),
              parseFloat(distance) // number 10000
            ),
            '=',
            'true'
          )
```

Comment: Hey man, this is the kind of answer we wish always to get! Thanks! I'm sure people will be happy of this info.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Anatoly for your answer. The code doesn't throw the error anymore, but it still doesn't work. No error, but it retrieves all activities of the table, despite the distance value.
Any clue for a solution?

The code looks like this now:

```
const result = await User.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: Activity,
          required: true,

          where: {
            [Op.and]: [
              Sequelize.where(
                Sequelize.fn(
                  'ST_DWithin',
                  Sequelize.col('point'),
                  Sequelize.fn(
                    'ST_SetSRID',
                    Sequelize.fn('ST_MakePoint', ownCoordinates[0], ownCoordinates[1]),
                  4326
                  ),
                  parseFloat(distance) * 5000
                ),
                true
              ),
              // other queries here
            ],
          },
        },
      ],
    })
```

Comment: Seems like you missed one argument `=` before `true`